# Couldn't Run ASP.NET Core in Linux Container using VS 2019

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, azure-aks

I was trying to have a sample application in AKS. I have Linux docker container running in Windows 10 Enterprise and just want to run an ASP.NET Core application locally in it using VS 2019.

It 1st displays below dialog.

[image]

I chosen yes and then it shows as below

[image]

> I couldn't see any certificate for localhost under MMC.exe. But once
>   running the command "dotnet dev-certs https", it shows "A valid HTTPS
>   certificate is already present.".
>
> Then if tries to trust that using "dotnet dev-certs https --trust". It
>   shows an error as "Trusting the HTTPS development certificate was
>   requested. A confirmation prompt will be displayed if the certificate
>   was not previously trusted. Click yes on the prompt to trust the
>   certificate. There was an error trusting HTTPS developer certificate."

Comment: run visual studio as administrator?

Comment: Yes. I am always running as Admin

Comment: I have the same problem, I solve it by exporting the certificate from the personal folder, and importing it to the Trusted Root Certification Entities folder. Although after company policy changes, this stopped working. Try if it helps.